# How to propertly retrieve the user in Blazor

Tags: asp.net, blazor, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side, httpcontext

I'am new in Blazor(server) and in ASP.NET Identity. I searched on internet how to retrieve the current logged in user. I'am using ASP.NET IDENTITY with the built-in functions. And I saw people that use SignInMananger and the AuthenticationState, or even the HttpContext. Now my question is: what's the difference, the advantages of using the first over the other?

Comment: It all depends on which authentication provider you're using.  Without that, who knows?  Without detail and specifics,  your question is likely to be closed

Comment: asp.net identity with built-in functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Authentication State - see this Ms Docs document which you've probably already read : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0.

SigninManager isn't really designed to work directly with Blazor - see this document that describes the issues. : https://startblazoring.com/Blog/SignInManager

HttpContext - The default Authentication State Provider does the work for you. It builds the `ClaimsPrincipal` object that represents the user from the HttpContext.

Comment: The Authentication State Provider use the HttpContext underneath.  And the SignInManager is not the right choice when we use Blazor right? (Summary)

Comment: Correct, unless you are rolling your own authentication process, use the AuthenticationStateProvider.